# Marquee in html

Tags: html, marquee

I want a "Continuous marquee text" over and over again... back to back... i dont want the text to finish scrolling completely before the next one starts... i want the same text to start scrolling and continue...

Answer (score 5):

Offtopic, but marquee (be it a `marquee` tag or jQuery-based one) [is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquee_tag) [evil](http://www.webdesignfromscratch.com/html-tag-reference/html-marquee-tag.php).

Comment: I like the `is` link, but the `evil` one is broken :/

Answer (score 2):

[jScroller2](http://jscroller2.markusbordihn.de/example/) probably does what you need without using the marquee tag.

The `marquee` tag should not be used since it is not a HTML or XHTML standard tag, it was invented for Internet Explorer and other browsers have it just for compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want a custom implementation I figure you will want to create one using JQuery. A Marquee should be quite easy to create. Have you looked for a readymade script on the Internet?